# How to create Dynamic steps on Chatbot in react native

Tags: react-native

I have to create the chat bot , so Do you have any example of a Dynamic Step component, which brings data from REST API and injects them into the react native chat bot?

Comment: Try this Library
https://github.com/LucasBassetti/react-native-chatbot

Comment: i try this library and i want import the REST API  to accessing the data.so how to use the REST API@Pramod